# InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90: Driver [linkedin] not supported

Tags: authentication, linkedin-api, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to get work with **social authentication** using liknedin provider in Laravel 5.1 but it's giving me that exception.
 I have implemented such authentication  using "github" and "google" providers,but this one sounds weird regarding  **linkedin provider is built-in in Laravel 5.1**

This is my redirect function

> ```
>       public function redirectToProvider($provider)
>      {
>        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
>      }
> ```

and  my setting

> ```
>   'linkedin' => [
>     'client_id' =>env('LinkedIn_APP_ID'),
>     'client_secret' => env('LinkedIn_APP_SECRET'),
>     'redirect' =>     'http://localhost:88/laravel/public/social/login/linkedin',
>    ]
> ```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual error?

Comment: @IllegalPigeon I did

Comment: Can we also see your code?

Comment: @IllegalPigeon I mentioned this is working fine with same code for google and github

Comment: That doesn't matter. Can you paste the code, otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: What does your config/app.php look like and the EventServiceProvider.php?

Comment: @IllegalPigeon I haven't changed my EventServiceProvider.php and I have added  Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider to my   providers in app file

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your redirect URL in your LinkedIn application's configuration (https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps)?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{           
    try 
    {
        $provider_user = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->user();
    }
    catch ( Exception $e ) 
    {
        $request->session()->flash( 'alert-danger', 'Invalid request data detected! please try again.' );
        return redirect( '/' );
    }
    dd($provider_user);  
}
```